# getting error while installing kured using fleet

Tags: docker, kubernetes, devops

the error iam getting is:

error while running post render on files:invalid cluster scoped object[name=namespaces-kured kind=ClusterRole apiversion:rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1]found.consider using "DefaultNamespace" not "namespace" in fleet.yaml

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for the delay in responding. There are specific cluster-wide resources that are not tied to a particular namespace. In order to avoid restricting all resources to a single namespace, it is recommended not to set the targetNamespace in the Rancher Continuous Delivery UI.